# Are exports in dll case sensitive?

Tags: windows, delphi, dll, case-sensitive

I was working on win7 and delphi 2010. Here is my code.

```
library CFGFunc;

uses
sysUtils
Un_ExFuncDll in "base\Un_ExFuncDll.pas"
...

exports
LoadExFuncsInDLL,
...
```

and Un_ExFuncDll.pas is here

```
unit Un_ExFuncDll;
interface    
uses
  Classes;
  procedure LoadexfuncsIndll(); stdcall;
  ...
```

After compiled, the dll doesn't work. However I replaced `LoadexfuncsIndll()` with
`LoadExFuncsInDLL()`(exactly match what is in exports) in `Un_ExFuncDll.pas`. It then worked.

Delphi is **case-insensitive**. But it seems that exports in dll are **case sensitive**.
So, what's the deal with them?

Comment: That's bound by the OS loader, winapi. See f.i. docs for GetProcAddress.

Comment: Sigh, if only Delphi were case sensitive .....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Importing/exporting DLL functions **IS** case-sensitive, and always has been.  That behavior is tied to the OS DLL loader, which is case-sensitive.  That is one of the only areas of the Delphi language that is case-sensitive.  This is documented behavior, at least in part:

[Writing Dynamically Loaded Libraries](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Writing_Dynamically_Loaded_Libraries)

> A **name** specifier consists of the directive **name** followed by a string constant. If an entry has no **name** specifier, the routine is exported under its original declared name, **with the same spelling and case**. Use a **name** clause when you want to export a routine under a different name.

[Procedures and Functions (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Importing_Functions_from_Libraries)

> In your importing declaration, **be sure to match the exact spelling and case of the routine's name**. Later, when you call the imported routine, the name is case-insensitive.

Comment: A lesson I learned long ago by some quick and simple tests to confirm by myself.

Comment: @Jerry Why write tests? Just read the docs. It is stated clearly in GetProcAddress docs on MSDN.

Comment: OT: I'd say procedure [`Register`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Declaring_the_Register_Procedure) is probably the last case sensitive thing in Delphi.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan All it takes is changing the case of an exported function and re-compiling and checking if it works

Comment: @JerryDodge All it takes is reading the documentations and then you know for sure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I trust the documentation only after I have some way verified it - tests/looking at the code/etc - very rarely take documentation at face value (these days)

Answer (score 0):

If you have hundreds of exported functions and an unknown number of dll's that have been written for your application, and you inadvertently camel case the name of some exported routine, it's a real PIA.

Here's one way to handle it...

```
procedure GetExportedFunctions(const ModulePath: string; names: TStringList);

  function RvaToVa(Module: HMODULE; Rva: Cardinal): Pointer;
  begin
    Result := Pointer(Rva + Module);
  end;

var
  Module: HMODULE;
  DosHeader: PImageDosHeader;
  NtHeaders: PImageNtHeaders;
  EntryData: PImageExportDirectory;
  POrd: PWord;
  p: PDWORD;
  i: integer;

begin
  names. Clear;

  Module := LoadLibraryEx(PChar(ModulePath), 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
  if Module = 0 then
       RaiseLastOSError;

  try
    DosHeader := PImageDosHeader(Module);
    NtHeaders := PImageNtHeaders(NativeUInt(Module) + DosHeader._lfanew);
    EntryData := RvaToVa(Module, NtHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress);

    if not Assigned(EntryData) then
         Exit;

    with EntryData^ do begin
      POrd := RvaToVa(Module, AddressOfNameOrdinals);
      p := RvaToVa(Module, AddressOfNames);
    end;

    { Function names }
    for i := 0 to EntryData^.NumberOfNames - 1 do begin
      names. Add(string(PAnsiChar(RvaToVa(Module, p^))));
      Inc(p);
      Inc(POrd);
    end;
  finally
    FreeLibrary(Module);
  end;
end; { GetExportedFunctions }

function GPA_CaseInsensitive(Module: HMODULE; const ProcName: string): Pointer;
var
  EnumNames: TStringList;
  i: integer;
  FuncName: string;

begin
  Result := nil;

  EnumNames := TStringList.Create;
  try
    GetExportedFunctions(GetModuleName(Module), EnumNames);
    for i := 0 to EnumNames.count - 1 do begin
      FuncName := EnumNames[i];
      if SameText(FuncName, ProcName) then begin
        Result := GetProcAddress(Module, PChar(FuncName));
        Break;
      end;
    end;

    if not Assigned(Result) then begin
      MessageBox(0, PChar(Format('Function %s not found in module', [ProcName])),
         'DLL Error', MB_SYSTEMMODAL or MB_SETFOREGROUND or MB_TOPMOST or MB_ICONHAND);
    end;
  finally
    EnumNames.Free;
  end;
end; { GPA_CaseInsensitive }
```